# MS Excel - Index/Match/Large Show Duplicates

Tags: excel, indexing, match

Here is my problem: there are 3 clients (A,B,C) who bought merchandise worth $5, $5, and $4 respectively.

If I use a regular `index(match(large...` the ranked list returned is A,A,C. This is shown in G88:G90 in the attached picture:

[image: ExcelProblem]

How do I get it to show A,B,C?

Answer (score 1):

Use this array formula:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$4,MATCH(1,(LARGE($B$2:$B$4,D2)=$B$2:$B$4)*(COUNTIF($E$1:E1,$A$2:$A$4)=0),0))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly the Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]